# Passing variable from popup to caller form

Tags: c#

I apologize if I've missed a blatantly obvious question that answers my problem.

I have a variable `newTeacherName` with no value initialized in the parent form `Edit_Class_Form`.

I have a popup `Change_Teacher_Popup` that has the user select a new value from a combo box `New_Teacher_Combobox`.

How do I have the parent form obtain the selected value from the combo box in the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Build a method in popup form returning selected value result then, after selection, pick it up in main form